# Admin user not able to login (Role based)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a functionality where Super Admin creates user. For Ex: SuperUser creates admin.

Then, I am unable to log in with the Admin details. The data of the admin is getting stored in the table. I am sure its role based issue. But I am not getting exactly where it is stucking. Please see the code for your reference:-

Role Define:-

```html
<div class="form_div">
    <div class="normalText3">
        <div class="txtlbl">Username:</div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form_txtfld"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ErrorMessage="*" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="normalText3">
        <div class="txtlbl">Password:</div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"  CssClass="form_txtfld"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ErrorMessage="*" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="normalText3">
        <div class="txtlbl"></div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="button-form" onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind for the login data:-

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String LoginID = txtUsername.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    String LoginPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

    LoginLogic _LoginLogic = new LoginLogic();
    DataSet dsLoginDetails = _LoginLogic.Ds_getLoginDetails(LoginID, LoginPassword);
    if (dsLoginDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (LoginID.ToLower() == "mserm")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = UserRoles.RELATIONSHIPMANAGER;
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("mseLoanApplications.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "msebo")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = UserRoles.BUSINESSOFFICER;
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("mseLoanApplications.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "mser")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = UserRoles.RISKOFFICER;
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("mseLoanApplications.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "fxadmin")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "fxadmin";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("rblfileuploader.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "mediaadmin")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "mediaadmin";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("mediakitadmin.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "dropboxadmin")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "dropboxadmin";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("dropboxadmin.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "careeradmin")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "careeradmin";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("CareerJobList.aspx");
        }
        else if (LoginID.ToLower() == "careersa")
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "careersa";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("CareerJobList.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["user"] = LoginID;
            Session["role"] = "admin";
            Session["password"] = LoginPassword;
            Response.Redirect("CareerJobList.aspx");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        String sc = "<Script>alert('Can not Login. Invalid Username or Password')</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "Ad" + DateTime.Now, sc, false);
    }

}
```

Please help, I tried debugging the code and I was getting null values.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through `_LoginLogic.Ds_getLoginDetails(..)` ? Is your username/password actually correct? Are you able to confirm this by looking at the database tables?

Comment: Yes, I tried it debugging and was getting null values. My username/password is also correct. Yes the data is also inserted in the table while creating admin user

Comment: What was `null` that you weren't expecting to be `null`?

Comment: Can you post the code for this method `_LoginLogic.Ds_getLoginDetails(..)` ?

Comment: Ok: namespace RBLogic
{
    public class LoginLogic
    {
        public LoginLogic();

        public void ChangePassword(string LoginID, string LoginPassword);
        public DataSet Ds_getLoginDetails(string LoginID, string LoginPassword);
    }
}

Comment: @RobH: The dsLoginDetails object values were null for the username and password.

Comment: Also, see the js fiddle for the masterPage:- http://jsfiddle.net/mvL94/

Comment: PLEASE avoid rolling your own membership provider. I already see so many security issues with your application I don't know where to start. No password hashing (unless it happens in getLoginDetails), tower of ifs, inconsistency in assigning your role to the session,... There are tried and tested methods to do this, especially in C# and ASP.Net. Use the membership provider you get when starting a new forms web application in VS.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: I agree with your point. It was already built their, changing again will disturb the whole application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code you provided in your comment for the `Ds_getLoginDetails` method:

```
public class LoginLogic
{
    public LoginLogic(); 
    public void ChangePassword(string LoginID, string LoginPassword); 
    public DataSet Ds_getLoginDetails(string LoginID, string LoginPassword);
}
```

The `Ds_getLoginDetails` method does not return any data and it does not query your database.

You when you initialise a new instance of `LoginLogic` and call `Ds_getLoginDetails` you are never actually returning an object.

Your login details should look something like:

```
public DataSet Ds_getLoginDetails(string LoginID, string LoginPassword)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string comes here"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Users where LoginID=@LoginID and Password=@Password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", LoginID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", LoginPassword);

        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say, I should return that object ?

Comment: Yes excactly, you need to query your database and return an object based on the query.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a sample of how your method should look and query a database to retrieve a dataset. Let us know if it is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I agree with ur answer, but my Ds_getLoginDetails(string LoginID, string LoginPassword) is coming from DLL library. It won't take the way  ur answered.

Comment: Is this your own class library or is it a third party's ?

Comment: My own dll file. Its ok seany84, i resolved it though. Thanks for your assistance.!